# template sms [SAMPLE TEST] by default

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-php

our template always put [SAMPLE TEST] as friendly name and we can not replace it. Somebody know the answer ?

we need know why the template always put [SAMPLE TEST] and how replace by our business name. thanks you for your help !!!

Comment: Can you please share in which country you are / which country code has the phone number that receives the code? Also, can you please share the code you use to send the message?